# поиск элементов масива numpy python

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть массив классов `numpy` и мне нужно найти те у которых значение переменной `pos` (внутри класса) равно определенному значению, не используя `for` (так как это слишком медленно).

Вот моя переменная `np.array([<class>, <class>, <class>])`  и мне нужно найти тот class у которого значение `pos` равен `[2, 2]`, при этом не используя `for` так как классов может быть до 13000 и `for` сильно тормозит.

Мне предложили использовать это:

```
import numpy as np 


class MyClass: 
    def __init__(self, pos): 
        self.pos = pos 
data = [MyClass(1), MyClass(2), MyClass(1), MyClass(3)] 
arr = np.array(data) 
target_value = 1 
result = arr[arr['pos'] == target_value] 
print(result)
```

но он выдает ошибку индекса

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
> numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: пример исходных данных и ваши попытки решения должны быть в текстовом виде в теле вопроса. иначе вопрос будет закрыт.

Comment: Абсолютно не понятен смысл хранения подобных данных в массиве numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
import numpy as np 


MyClass = np.dtype([("pos", np.int32)])

arr = np.array([[1], [2], [1], [3]], dtype=MyClass)

target_value = 1 
result = arr[arr["pos"] == target_value] 
print(result)
```

Comment: Интересный вариант!

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл на английском SO ещё один интересный вариант [с преобразованием объекта в строку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66203231/8324991). Не уверен, что он вам подойдёт, но вдруг:

```py
import numpy as np 

class MyClass: 
    def __init__(self, pos): 
        self.pos = pos

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pos)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MyClass(Pos={self.pos})"

data = [MyClass(1), MyClass(2), MyClass(1), MyClass(3)] 
arr = np.array(data) 
target_value = '1'
result = arr[arr.astype(str) == target_value] 
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
[MyClass(Pos=1) MyClass(Pos=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Иногда невозможно обойтись без циклов и невозможно ускорить ваш код - это и ваш случай. :-(

NumPy предназначен для быстрого обращения *только с простыми типами объектов, прежде всего с числами*, а не с объектами каких-то собственных классов. Значит, и не стоит превращать список объектов вашего класса в `numpy array` - вы не получите ни какого преимущества из того.

Также только

```
class MyClass: 
    def __init__(self, pos): 
        self.pos = pos 
        
data = [MyClass(1), MyClass(2), MyClass(1), MyClass(3)] 
target_value = 1 
result = [obj for obj in data if obj.pos == target_value]
print(result)
```

---

*Вывод (у вас будут другие адреса):*

> ```
> [<__main__.MyClass object at 0x00000000141E8A60>, <__main__.MyClass object at 0x00000000141E8340>]
> ```